# Makefile: save errors and print at the end

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile snipt which runs some tests:

```
MKFILES = $(wildcard $(addprefix $(UNIT_TEST_SRC)/,$(subst $(comma), ,*.mk))))
TESTS = $(MKFILES:.mk=.test)

%.test:%.mk
  @make -f $?

run_tests: $(TESTS)
```

The above works fine, but I'm trying to change it so that instead of aborting when a test errors, it continues and prints out all failures at the end.

```
FAILURES := 

%.test:%.mk
  @make -f $? || $(MAKE) $@.error

.PHONY: %.test.error
%.test.error:
  $(eval FAILURES += $@)

run_tests: $(TESTS)
   @echo "Failures:" $(FAILURES)
```

It seems like my `eval` is not surviving the `%.test.error` scope, If I move the `eval` to the `%.test` then it does survive, although that's not what I want.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recipe of the following rule:

```
%.test:%.mk
   @make -f $? || $(MAKE) $@.error
```

`make` is called, and another new running instance of `make` is created. It is in that instance where the `eval` takes place. Therefore, it has no effect for the parent `make` instance that executed that recipe above.

---

Instead, you could create true `.test.error` files when an error occurs:

```
%.test:%.mk
   @make -f $? || touch $@.error
```

and remove them when you are done:

```
run_tests: $(TESTS)
   @echo "Failures:" $(FAILURES)
   @$(RM) *.test.error
```

The definition of `FAILURES` could be then:

```
FAILURE = $(wildcard *.test.error)
```

That way, `FAILURE` will be expanded when `run_tests` recipe's is executed (i.e.: deferred expansion by using a *recursively expanded variable*) and therefore it will contain the list of the `.test.error` files (if any).

Comment: Thanks! I think for you last list you mean: 
`FAILURES = $(wildcard *.test.error)` which will actually defer the initialization: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html

Comment: How right you are! that was a *simply expanded variable* (`:=`), and a *recursively expanded variable* (`=`) is what is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Followup question: When I do something like:
`@echo "Failures:" $(FAILURES)`

it works as expected, but if I do something like: `ifneq ($(FAILURES),)
  $(error The following tests failed: $(FAILURES))
endif` Then `FAILURES` seems to be evaluated at the start, not when it is used.

Comment: That's because the `ifneq` is evaluated when parsing the makefile and therefore `FAILURES` is expanded as well at the very beginning.

Comment: You could create an additional *phony* and empty target, e.g.: `check-errors`. Then call `make` recursively on the same makefile (as you did originally) for that target `check-errors`, but passing the `FAILURES` variable on the command line. That is: `$(MAKE) check-errors FAILURES="$(FAILURES)"`. That way, the 2nd time the makefile is parsed, `FAILURES` has the value you want it to have when the `ifneq` is evaluated.

Comment: I ended up going with something like `$(if $(FAILURES), $(error The following tests failed: $(FAILURES)))` That seemed to have the desired effect

Comment: I think that `$(if ...)` is as well evaluated before the recipe of the rule that creates the `.test.error` files gets executed and therefore `FAILURES` won't be expanded to the value you want it to expanded (i.e.: the list of `.test.error` files), isn't it? I mean, `$(if ...)` is basically evaluated when it is found (i.e.: when the makefile is being parsed, before any rule match takes place).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$(MAKE) $@.error`, it invokes a new instance of make, and `FEATURES` gets set there.   The new value does not get propagated to the parent make.

I might suggest using a temporary file/folder as so:

```
.PHONY: prep
prep:
    rm -rf failures;
    mkdir failures;

%.test:%.mk: | prep
    @make -f $? || touch failures/$@.error

run_tests: $(TESTS)
    @echo "Failures:"
    @cd failures && ls || true
    @rm -rf failures
```